# Where should I execute code that contains #include <xdevcfg.h> and xil_printf?

Tags: c, fpga, xilinx

I have code and I don't know where to compile it. I am getting the messages No such file or directory for particular .h files that I am including.
I am using gcc -o main main.c as a command line to compile it.

Comment: You'll need to add the directory that contains "xdevcfg.h" to your include path.

Comment: This looks like should be compiled with xilinx cross-compiler. Also your title says "execute", while the question asks about "compile". These are two different things.

Comment: @EugeneSh. sorry yes, I was thinking about compiling

Answer (score 0):

If the file you are trying to include is not in the same directory you are compiling in then you need to use the GCC include option to include the path.

```
gcc -Idir [options] [source files] [object files] [-o output file]
```

See a helpful link [here](https://www.rapidtables.com/code/linux/gcc/gcc-i.html).